# Add column to materialized view

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have an existing materialized view in Oracle. 
But I want to add more columns to it. I saw that it is not possible to execute
`CREATE OR REPLACE` to the materialized view so how can I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: `drop materialized view ..; create materialized view ... `

Comment: But if I do a 'DROP' and the materialized view doesn't exist, the database will give me an error, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the columns to the base table and after that run a refresh in the MV.

```
declare
begin
  DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('your_mv', 'f');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from dba_objects where status='INVALID';

grant create materialized view to <schema>;
grant create table to <schema>;

drop MATERIALIZED VIEW <schema>.<mvname>;

  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW <schema>.<mvname>
  (...)
  AS SELECT (...);

select * from  <schema>.<mvname>;


revoke create materialized view from <schema>;
revoke create table from <schema>;

select * from dba_objects where status='INVALID';
```